# Converter Template Biométrico

Tags: vb.net

Venho tentando gerar um template biométrico a partir de um leitor Hamster DX da nitgen. Esse template biométrico devera ser enviado para um relógio de ponto da TopData, um Inner rep Plus, porém o template que ele me gera é puro e em dois formatos. Um array de bytes e/ou uma string, contudo o que vai pro relógio é um template convertido que parece ser hexadecimal, mas mesmo convertido para hexadecimal ele gera de uma forma diferente. O template que vai pro relógio sempre possui 808 caracteres, uma sequencia de 7 zeros no inicio seguido de 1 três, o que vem após isso é aleatório

Biometria que o relógio aceita

```
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
```

Biometria que o leitor gera em array de bytes (Converti para string)

```
2321002024688128302362151293211065206136158108172671181342411681581391713105146215237882221051201041962421623466246195110174392551102251161018830821201212363439160391021063778114184853106815722111311193225991152521911148117449150240249171218659719221452184130150236701037219121690229422504918414818011217110310520623213296267010494142611761181454254241686725011764185224166332071995620191743539159188172181103221919168202170118255809911523584541741841101871713633662531252234119022738597417820214305824222112512502161825116121321813811515111713317317920910738802021641891994186190675109886162321548023360255190921610622331105972354710823416320225219211520223138122415015578139152172106216813017514107717015217118213520923723513585164158209207219982552672271272125019710537161472022412413011313526112009381335622371952081915534174107605749145562011553663148851451172488459222228142231204243121163186255200485920219224523277195981585312522818422361971151949413614748321412352342506836219220321414997361444914124720715747121102174811618824825213825025319320415315113913020051941902187321841601620818241243217231209208101062151882102201738715412515986971811464563806122721314023716815225272081812132062175962728379168217341971102260202160208451162921649149282081992182332231402291122391681319724169
```

Biometria que o leitor gera em string

```
AQAAABQAAAD0AQAAAQASAAMAZAAAAAAA6AEAAMfj53h2ljjbpA1OySQbu/FTD3fAM4RTLStGw3RZuIsf6jZ6A5ChCMjEf22dlmOflpIXNKDEhf91gYI4M9Gs4M22OJbh2rV5edOQVplBnzmTnW1my8u1Ad0oQjtEA*AcwRjk7nhPtQGE402aHJ0S9ocX5R0Qq5reXyNskmvbIN8UQ92URD*bcpKUClXRiR/GPPso2PHDGA7V*KzFjcQaIC1MpAUU/qRUtHsUES87hyOEbZK9v25dkD0s9vU9D0Nzxj4D4h7BWCieRkD4YB3TzwujGR8*A9OaJsKXSIs5RGtxqgCwoN4SREQ31E/yvBrXcU0R/KOAqU4N0pGJGIlgCKHmHoVHmzcxg35WjJG6VZaKmBvvwSjrIeQM*0aHs39Cw4sc7zIalHbTUNSJOwC8lHRll5zNVWIdzoqch0vPSuvmvoZpXPZnle7qXuDVKbwYqE6NQOBYgg3F4tmcwwb9RLDvhPBTRnzrx/WX*iJSy4tnHL4UrhGG4u1vuC4OfI3j6Sbkv6DalbBQhIvJ3Mfak/3mWfnlhIhbcDkJoFrHDsl3DrEonTVwmyuU02TZhxEzVyAhQYqmGv3tMUwYmTYindiHUnpv2yf9hrB0M8rhFWIqGAK5wSxCYOxfL6cjenueu3J0t9M3MpOSHiShrgKHGHI
```

Método que usei para transforma em hexadecimal os bytes gerados pelo leitor

```
Private bytesConvertidos As String

    Public Function ConverterBytesParaHexadecimal(BytesNaoConvertidos As Byte()) As String

        For x = 0 To UBound(BytesNaoConvertidos) - 1

            ' Conversao para hexadecimal
            bytesConvertidos += Hex(BytesNaoConvertidos(x))

        Next

        Return bytesConvertidos

    End Function
```

Array de bytes gerados pelo leitor convertidos para hexadecimal com o método acima

```
DC1001664341329E9BDA156032D62CDA62C9097E6A467973C96CD593FF35D9E42AD4EB079428D895891F740557EE7C460BBB13A5CB54950A14826B99C4C5A2944A82724E4C9AE349529B37E2923FE4C7D5D1BC3220A997107C35181FBB94CC8157DC8BCDE4736F9CC13C15B3D9DBAB104DCEF64FEDADDDC4C3E4F8B68A4D3C3AED6D2199EB7159042C0557E98B1034B54B2719CE3C3857E5403FA677DED9D548349136FC4D212B2CDCE5AD852AFB699FD53EE4E3945F65EDE13CA8FD9724D3489D7BEA223A7A8E73AF8C1CF6FA26CD154A7C33C4785C4D82CE6256F16274D6555B655F146ACE24221CF1BFE0AF899451D1F41ACA4A10D34CD10F3AAEE51320B5AA1FD61097D06F2AACCA1BB4887734ED58041A1A232FBD7F771C4924E59B173B01FF6417F98BD8D5118BCBC579516191B894EA8C112674AF5712B758DECA982A6BB96F5D54423353C157694E3A9B28955E78D825B1585BA05F9CF5BA34C38AC95DD78E7F3A7AB0333F319114A217D26D7D42F6184AA43D740DA791F2C8E79C7EF805F589281948B63D8E64E67BCCDAB9586D97888EE09446224856ABEE41AED12CB5FF6B1E890C3FC3A2FAA08E757079B2989C4DF46A4C47C3846C57ED0547A19B4F1BE87238C1EBC16E317959E1ABCAF12F77B435A
```

Já tentei converter a string para bytes e depois pra hexa

Exemplos em C# também resolveria o problema

Comment: Olá, qual é a marca e modelo do relógio?

Comment: Topdata, inner rep plus

Comment: Está codificado em Base64

Comment: Não é Base64, mas sim Base32.